# Extract subarray from jagged array and use as 1d array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to reduce redundancy in my macros but I'm struggling with getting an element from a jagged array and using it elsewhere.
The premise is a single workbook with many sheets being split by groups of sheet names into new documents that I can then send to the process owners so they only get their own data.

Previously I was selecting sheet names listed explicitly and pasting to a new document that was named explicitly, but I had to run 10 separate almost identical macros to do that and I have heard of select being a bad choice in many instances as well.

Below is my latest attempt, the first issue is at the printOut line I get a Type Mismatch.

```
Sub CopyOut()
Dim printOut, groupNames, Group1, groupArray() As Variant
Dim n, j As Long
Dim reNamed, fileName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
groupNames = Array("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4") 'other arrays left off for length
Group1 = Array("FA_1A Report", "FA_1A", "FA_2ACS Report", "FA_2ACS", "FA_2BCS Report", "FA_2BCS", "FANUCMED Report", "FANUCMED", "FA_RRTP1 Report", "FA_RRPT1")
groupArray = Array(groupNames, Group1)

For n = 1 To UBound(groupArray)
    fileName = "CS Data Sheet" & " " & Format(Date, "mmmyy") & "-" & groupArray(n - n)(n - 1) & ".xlsm" 'concat file name string. this is not just tacked on the end of reName because i use it on it's own later
    reNamed = "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\" & fileName 'concat save location string
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add 'create a new workbook, wb2
    wb2.SaveAs fileName:=reNamed, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled  'save with that name and location
    printOut = Join(Application.Index(groupArray, n, 0), ",")
    wb1.Sheets(printOut).Copy Before:=Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(1) 'copy the sheets for the group and paste into the newly created document
Next
End Sub
```

If I nix printOut altogether and put in a specific worksheet name instead it does work for just that one sheet (of course) but I need it to copy multiple to each new document.

I have also tried:

```
For n = 1 To UBound(groupArray)
...
for j= LBound(groupArray(n)) To UBound(groupArray(n))
wb1.Sheets(groupArray(n)(j)).Copy Before:=Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(1)
next
next
```

to iterate through the subarray and copy a sheet at a time, but it gives subscript out of range. With this version I tried various methods of making the groupArray(n)(j) value into a string or into a "worksheet" type to set as a variable and use the variable in the sheets().copy, to no avail.

Any idea where I could be going wrong?
thanks so much

EDIT:
I got my above code working by wrapping it in split (was trying to use printOut as an array when it was only a string) and fixing the arguments of Index as below, however the resulting code still needs work, since if a sheet is missing it won't run.

```
printOut = Split(Join(Application.Index(groupArray(n), 1, 0), ","), ",")
```

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding how the `groupNames`, `Group1` and `GroupArray` are supposed to work together. Just from that fact alone, I'd say you're overly complicating a solution here. Perhaps write a `Function` that will take a group name and an index and give you a worksheet name. That way you keep your main logic streamlined and only make a single call to work out which name you need.

Comment: @PeterT groupArray is an array of the arrays of sheet names that belong to each group (plus groupNames, which I only use to name the documents). it's absolutely possible I am over complicating, but I'm not sure I understand the function idea--Pulling out a worksheet name by it's index is what I am trying (and failing) to do by iterating through n and j in the second section. If I did make a function, how should I pass it in from being 2d into .copy? thank you, I am only a trial and error learner of VBA,I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you find yourself hard-coding values like sheet names, group names, and other data directly in your code it tends to become difficult to maintain. Adding more groups, or re-shuffling the sheets in each group becomes problematic. My recommendation is to create a (possibly hidden) worksheet that maps your worksheet names into groups. Then you have a small set of code that operates directly on that.

My example data is set up like this:

[image]

Next, in its own code module, I created a few methods to work directly with this group map data. The main idea here is to move the group map data into a [memory-based array](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Reading_from_a_Range_to_the_VBA_Array). While in general I rarely use module-level global variables, I have one in this example to illustrate how to work with the data by only reading it into the array once every time the macro is executed.

*(These are `Subs` and `Functions`. For my own code, I likely would have created a VBA class to handle the data in an object-oriented way.)*

So there is a `Private Sub` to get the data:

```
Option Explicit

Private groupData As Variant

Private Sub GetGroupData()
    Const GROUP_WS_NAME As String = "GroupMap"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(GROUP_WS_NAME)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    With ws
        '--- how many columns of groups?
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastRow = .UsedRange.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        groupData = .Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, lastCol).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Now it's easy to figure out how many groups there are:

```
Public Function NumberOfGroups() As Long
    If IsEmpty(groupData) Then GetGroupData
    NumberOfGroups = UBound(groupData, 2)
End Function
```

And how many items in a particular group:

```
Public Function NumberInGroup(ByVal groupNumber As Long)
    If IsEmpty(groupData) Then GetGroupData
    '--- count the number of array values that have data
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(groupData, 1) To UBound(groupData, 1)
        If groupData(i, groupNumber) = vbNullString Then
            '--- we found the first empty cell in this array, we're done
            Exit For
        Else
            NumberInGroup = NumberInGroup + 1
        End If
    Next i
    '--- subtract one to discount the header value
    NumberInGroup = NumberInGroup - 1
End Function
```

The easiest of all is getting the value of any group:

```
Public Function GetGroupValue(ByVal groupNumber As Long, _
                              ByVal groupIndex As Long) As Variant
    If IsEmpty(groupData) Then GetGroupData
    '--- always add one to the index to account for the header value
    GetGroupValue = groupData(groupIndex + 1, groupNumber)
End Function
```

Notice the check for `If IsEmpty(groupData) Then GetGroupData` at the beginning of each method. This makes sure the `groupData` array is always loaded if necessary.

This example gives it a quick test (in a different code module):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim totalGroups As Long
    totalGroups = NumberOfGroups()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    For i = 1 To totalGroups
        Dim totalInGroup As Long
        totalInGroup = NumberInGroup(i)
        For j = 1 To totalInGroup
            Debug.Print "group " & i & " = " & GetGroupValue(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here's the whole group data code module in a single block:

```
Option Explicit

Private groupData As Variant

Private Sub GetGroupData()
    Const GROUP_WS_NAME As String = "GroupMap"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(GROUP_WS_NAME)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    With ws
        '--- how many columns of groups?
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastRow = .UsedRange.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        groupData = .Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, lastCol).Value
    End With
End Sub

Public Function NumberOfGroups() As Long
    If IsEmpty(groupData) Then GetGroupData
    NumberOfGroups = UBound(groupData, 2)
End Function

Public Function NumberInGroup(ByVal groupNumber As Long)
    If IsEmpty(groupData) Then GetGroupData
    '--- count the number of array values that have data
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(groupData, 1) To UBound(groupData, 1)
        If groupData(i, groupNumber) = vbNullString Then
            '--- we found the first empty cell in this array, we're done
            Exit For
        Else
            NumberInGroup = NumberInGroup + 1
        End If
    Next i
    '--- subtract one to discount the header value
    NumberInGroup = NumberInGroup - 1
End Function

Public Function GetGroupValue(ByVal groupNumber As Long, ByVal groupIndex As Long) As Variant
    If IsEmpty(groupData) Then GetGroupData
    '--- always add one to the index to account for the header value
    GetGroupValue = groupData(groupIndex + 1, groupNumber)
End Function
```

Comment: Awesome! Our groups don't change often, but I will implement some of this as best practice and it's given me an idea for another way to do groups as well

Answer (score 0):

If I got this right, you have one master workbook with n sheets and you want to group some of them, then create a new workbook for each group and paste in its assigned sheets.

I think an approach where you keep a "config" file in your master workbook for setting up groups and sheets, is more suitable rather than editing into code. Example:

[image]

The below code will create a file using the names from column A and copy all the sheets defined on their respective row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyOut()
    Dim groupArr() As Variant
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, highestNumOfSheets As Long, i As Long, j As Long, arrColumns As Long
    Dim reNamed As String, fileName As String, configSheet As String
    Dim removedSheet1 As Boolean

    ' Modify the sheet name here
    configSheet = "config"

    ' Build an array from sheet defined groups
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(configSheet)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            lastCol = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If lastCol > highestNumOfSheets Then highestNumOfSheets = lastCol
        Next i

        groupArr = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, highestNumOfSheets)).Value2
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = LBound(groupArr) To UBound(groupArr)
        fileName = "CS Data Sheet " & Format(Date, "mmmyy") & "-" & groupArr(i, 1) & ".xlsm"
        reNamed = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\" & fileName

        removedSheet1 = False   ' Reset this on each new workbook created
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add

        ' Pick all the sheet names for the current group
        For j = 2 To UBound(groupArr, 2)

            ' Skip empty values from array (if it's the case) and skip missing sheets
            If Trim(groupArr(i, j)) <> vbNullString And SheetExists(groupArr(i, j)) Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(groupArr(i, j)).Copy Before:=wb2.Worksheets(1)

                ' Remove Sheet1 from the new Workbook
                If removedSheet1 = False Then
                    With Application
                        .DisplayAlerts = False
                        wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
                        removedSheet1 = True
                        .DisplayAlerts = True
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next j

        ' Here you might need an error handler if you think you're going to run the macro multiple times in the same day
        ' If the file exists already this will throw an error
        ' A quick lazy way is to add time (including seconds) when you define the file name above

        wb2.SaveAs fileName:=reNamed, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        wb2.Close
        If Not wb2 Is Nothing Then Set wb2 = Nothing
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function SheetExists(ByVal sheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        SheetExists = True
        Set ws = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Of course it can be tweaked around, with error handling and other checks (depending on what you want to achieve entirely) but it should give you an alternative view of your code.

EDIT: Added a function to check if sheet exists.

Comment: This is really great, definitely what I'm going for! one question is that sometimes a sheet does not exist because no transactions were done at that station (which is was what giving me the subscript out of range initially). I definitely like the idea of having a config sheet where the groups are defined, but either my ugly way or yours, I can't figure how to account for if a sheet that is "assigned" to a group doesn't exist...I could change my other macros to always make every sheet and then after copying delete blank ones maybe?

Comment: I'm afraid in VBA there isn't a really elegant way to check for that (not that I'm aware of, at least). However, I've edited the code and added a little function that should help with your issue.